# Apache Redirect or Rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdirectory

I currently have an issue with my new website.

The live site is within a subdirectory called "live".
So, my URLs look like this: www.example.com/live/specials/

I would like my URLs to look like this: www.example.com/specials/

This is what I have in my .htaccess in the root dir:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ live/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ live/$1
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you posted? Does it redirect to the wrong location? Do you get an error?

Comment: No errors, and it works fine.  But I don't want to see the "live/" in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?!live/).*)$ live/$1 [L]
```

Place this in `/live/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /live/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /live/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This line of code does the same thing my code was doing.  Still shows the "live/" in the URL.

Comment: You need to enter URL as `www.example.com/specials/` and rule will add / live/ in it.

Comment: To redirect `www.example.com/live/specials/` to `www.example.com/specials/` see my updated answer. Remember to place new rule in `/live/.htaccess`.